# How to automate SSRS using jenkins?

Tags: reporting-services

I have around 700 reports and my organisation uses Jenkins as CI, is there a way I can automate build & deployment for SSRS using Jenkins ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use [nodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql-ssrs), to create and deploy your SSRS reports.

Or you could use the [report server utilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/report-server-command-prompt-utilities-ssrs)

Both way you will be calling a script from Jenkins, which either takes the already built reports, or build the reports and than deploy!

Comment: Please add some details from linked article